# Create list with alternating values

Tags: python

I'm looking to create a list whose values alternate based on a set of known patterns. Note that there may not be an equal number of items with each prefix. (2 foos, 3 bars, 3 spams). My current solution is nasty gaggle that .pop()'s from lists built from common prefixes and appends to a new list.

```
prefix_patterns = ['foo','bar','spam']

inlist = ['fooABC','fooXYZ','barABC','barXYZ','spamABC','bar123','spamXYZ','spam123']
```

Desired output:

```
outlist = ['fooABC','barABC','spamABC','fooXYZ','barXYZ','spamXYZ','bar123','spam123']
```

Current solution (doesn't handle lists of differing lengths):

```
foos = [value for value in inlist if 'foo' in value]
bars = [value for value in inlist if 'bar' in value]
spams = [value for value in inlist if 'spam' in value]

while foos:
    outlist.append(foos.pop())
    outlist.append(bars.pop())
    outlist.append(spams.pop())
```

For context: Looking to use this as a sort of throttling mechanism when making requests to 4 different servers.

Comment: generators are always a fun way to do things like this.. they save on memory too

Comment: Could you show your current solution.

Comment: Are the words sharing a prefix always sorted in inlist? foo<str> always befotre bar<str> before spam<str>

Comment: Shouldn't be words with `123` be before `ABC` according to lexicographical sorting?

Comment: @kabanus No, they are in random order

Comment: @leaf done.....

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @LMc 2.7.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using **Python 2.x** this would work:

```
# group by prefix first -> [['fooXX']['barXX']['spamXX']]
prefix_match = [[x for x in inlist if x.startswith(pre)] for pre in prefix_patterns]
outlist = [x for i in map(None,*prefix_match) for x in i if x]
```

The `map` built-in function will zip `prefix_match` together and pad with `None` if one of the lists is too short. Then you can simply flatten this list and exclude any `None` objects.

For **Python 3.x** you could replace the map function with [itertools.zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import zip_longest
prefix_match = [[x for x in inlist if x.startswith(pre)] for pre in prefix_patterns]
outlist = [x for i in zip_longest(*prefix_match) for x in i if x]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
inlist =['fooABC','fooXYZ','barABC','barXYZ','spamABC','bar123','spamXYZ','spam123']

new_inlist = []

separator = '-'

# Adding separator, I believe it won't require in real scenario as there must be separator between host and user.
for prefix in ['foo', 'bar', 'spam']:
    for item in inlist:
        if item.startswith(prefix):
           new_inlist.append(item.replace(prefix, prefix + separator))

# Ultimately new_inlist ->
#['foo-ABC','foo-XYZ','bar-ABC','bar-XYZ','spam-ABC','bar-123','spam-XYZ','spam-123']

# Now Just do sorting
new_inlist.sort(key=lambda x: x.split(separator)[1])
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question: Sorting isn't mentioned or asked for. Why is it being provided?

Comment: I think in question James didn't mention that he is not looking for sort solution that is why I added sort solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html) recipe roundrobin.

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

prefix_patterns = ['foo','bar','spam']
inlist = ['fooABC','fooXYZ','barABC','barXYZ','spamABC','bar123','spamXYZ','spam123']
outlist = ['fooABC','barABC','spamABC','fooXYZ','barXYZ','spamXYZ','bar123','spam123']

def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    pending = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while pending:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))

def check_prefix(item):
    for prefix in prefix_patterns:
        if item.startswith(prefix):
            return prefix

group = {}
for item in inlist:
    key = check_prefix(item)
    group.setdefault(key, []).append(item)
print([x for x in roundrobin(*list(group.values()))])

>> ['barABC', 'spamABC', 'fooABC', 'barXYZ', 'spamXYZ', 'fooXYZ', 'bar123', 'spam123']
```